# SQL: IF OBJECT_ID() and IF EXISTS don't work in conjunction with UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2017, I have a View called `Foo`, what I'm trying to do is to check if `Foo` is a user-defined table, if Yes, do an `UPDATE`, else do not do anything.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('Foo') AND xtype = 'U')
   UPDATE Foo SET .....
```

Here I check if the `Foo` exist and if it is a user-defined table (`xtype='U'`).
Since `Foo` is a View, so `xtype='U'` should be `false` and the `UPDATE` should not execute, but the problem is that the `UPDATE` still execute, and error occurred.

```
Update or insert of view or function 'Foo' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.
```

When I execute the sql query below, indeed there is no record is returned, so the `EXISTS` should return `false`.

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('Foo') and xtype = 'U'
```

I've also tried this, but same problem, `UPDATE` still execute.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Foo', 'U')
   UPDATE Foo SET .....
```

But, if I change the `UPDATE` statement into say a `PRINT` statement, then it works fine.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('Foo') and xtype = 'U')
   PRINT 'A'
```

In this case, `A` is not printed, and the command executed successfully.

```
Commands completed successfully.
```

So, my question is why the `IF EXISTS` or `IF OBJECT_ID` I used above don't work with `UPDATE`?
Am I missing something or I am doing it wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Without a [mre] I can't test thus, but I suspect this is a parser error. The parser is checking the batch, saying that there is a problem (you have an `UPDATE` against an invalid object type), and then errorring. No SQL is even run.

Comment: Also, stop using objects like `sysobjects` and use the `sys` schema objects (`sys.objects`). Those objects are just there for backward compatibility for SQL Server **2000** syntax and could easily be removed in a future version: [sys.sysobjects (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Per Larnu, when the batch is compiled the object must exist, otherwise an error occurs before anything is ever executed. To get this to work you need to wrap the `UPDATE` in an `EXEC`.

Comment: `don't work in conjunction` they do. What fails is the way you try to write and execute a *single* SQL batch that tries to update a table only if it exists. A batch is compiled as a single unit, so if the table doesn't exist, compilation fails before the query is even executed. Very few people attempt to do what you tried. Typically maintenance scripts *create* tables if they don't exist

Comment: The maintenance scripts executed with SSMS or sqlcmd use `GO` to break the script in batches. First one batch creates missing tables and is terminated with `GO`. The rest of the batches in the script can work with the tables after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put the update directly behind the IF OBJECT_ID... however, you can execute the SQL this way:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[...]', N'U') IS NOT NULL
  EXEC('UPDATE...')
GO
```